# Converting array list object to jsonarray

Tags: java, android, json

I have arraylist that needs to be converted to json array to post in the server

the format of json should be like this:

```
{
   p:1,
   s:["a":1,"b":2],["a":2,"b":3],["a":3,"b":4]
}
```

Let say I have:

```
List<MyObject> objectList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject .setA(1);
myObject .setB(2);

myObject .setA(2);
myObject .setB(3);

myObject .setA(3);
myObject .setB(4);

objectList.add(myObject);
```

My current code is:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        JSONArray ar = new JSONArray();
        ar.put("a:"+objectList.get(i).getA());
        ar.put("b:"+objectList.get(i).getB());

        jOuter.put("s",ar);
    }
```

but this doesnt work, the current return is:

```
{"p":1,"s":["a:20","b:10.0"]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That json you show is far from valid. Keys must be strings, values can be lists `[ ]`, but lists cannot contain key value pairs, those go in objects `{ }`

Comment: @Cris You can look into Gson library..

Comment: you are putting to your `JSONArray` a `String`, while you should put `JSONObject`

Comment: how about putting it in a hashmap then add it to json? i just need the json format above.

Comment: do you think {"p":1, "s"[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}] are valid and the same that i need?

Comment: @Cris : Invalid Json ..!!

Comment: @Cris This json is invalid. Please check my answer. You can use [Json Viwer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to check and verify your json format.

Comment: thanks, will check that

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be something like this?

```
JSONArray ar = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {

        JSONObject objects = new JSONObject();
        objects.put("a", objectlist.get(i).getA();
        objects.put("b", objectlist.get(i).getB();

        ar.put(objects);

    }
        jOuter.put("s",ar);
```

Comment: return is {"p":1,"s":[{"a":1,"b":2},{}]}

Comment: Someone already did it: the JSON array has to be outside the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Your `s` entry is actually a `JsonArray`,  while your `p` is just a property. Here I am using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) but you could easily apply it to whichever library you are using. So you can do the following:

```
JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject();
jObj.addProperty("p", 1);

JsonArray sArr  = new JsonArray();

 for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++)
 {
        JsonObject innerObj = new JsonObject();
        innerObj.addProperty("a:"+objectList.get(i).getA());
        innerObj.addProperty("b:"+objectList.get(i).getB());

        sArr.add(innerObj);
 }

 jObj.addProperty("s", sArr);
```

The output is:

```
{
  "p":1,
  "s":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your required format is invalid.
I think you are looking for something like this

```
{
  "p": 1,
  "s": [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    },
    {
      "a": 2,
      "b": 3
    },
    {
      "a": 3,
      "b": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

For this code will be like as below

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
        job.put("a",objectList.get(i).getA());
        job.put("b",objectList.get(i).getB());

        jArray .put(job);
}

try {
        jOuter.put("s", jArray );
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code: This will make the proper formatting:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jo.put("p", "1");

        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
        for (MyObject listItem : objectList) {
            JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
            inner.put("a", listItem.getA());
            inner.put("b", listItem.getB());

            jarr.put(inner);
        }
        jo.put("s", jarr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It will return output like:

```
{
  "p":1,
  "s":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3},{"a":3,"b":4}]
}
```

This makes a proper json, which I think you need! Do let me know, if I am wrong somewhere.